# CSS styling the Header,Navigation,Footer,and Section/Aside.....How do i make everything fixed?

Tags: css, html

CSS styling the Header,Navigation,Footer,and Section/Aside.....How do i make everything fixed?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
</head>
<title>
menu
</title>
<style>

#header {position:relevant;
background-color:#59d5d8;
color:white;
text-align:center;
padding:.45px;
backgroung-image:url(C:\Users\ASUS\Desktop\whitelogoooo.gif) top;
}

#nav {display:auto;
position:auto;
line-height:30px;
background-color:#818181;
height:600px;
width:195px;
float:left;
padding:10px;
text-decoration:none;}

ul li{list-style:none;
    width:166px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #dfdfdf;
    padding: 21.5px
    transition: opacity .2s, margin-left .1s;
    }

ul li a {text-decoration:none;
        font-family:Comic Sans Ms,Arial;
        color:#fff;
        font-size:20px;
        text-transformation:uppercase;
        text-shawdow:0 0 1px rgba(0,0,0,.1);}


#section {
width:540px;
padding:20px;
}
#footer {
background-color:#59d5d8;
color:white;
clear:both;
text-align:center;
padding:5px;
text-align:bottom;}
</style>

</head>
<body>

<div id="header">
<img src="C:\Users\ASUS\Desktop\whitelogoooo.gif" height="400" width="500"        alt="logo" align="middle">
</div>


<div id="nav">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">HOME</a></li><br>           
        <li><a href="#">GALLERY</a></li><br>
        <li><a href="#">VIDEOS </a></li><br>
        <li><a href="#"> SLATE</a></li><br>
        <li><a href="#">CONTACT US </a></li><br>
        <li><a href="#">ABOUT US </a></li><br>
    </ul>
</div>

<div id="section">
<aside>
<h1>Welcome :)</h1>
<p>
 Education is the foundation of life, and without education there is no life.
As humans we will one day pass from this earth leaving behind us a legacy and a responsibility to the generations that follow; this responsibility is to lead mankind and to guarantee progression.
This can be achieved by starting at the very beginning, as the solution to any answer has to be solved from the beginning; our children are the answer and our educational system is the problem.
    </p>

    <p>
Nowadays, children are being subjected to a great deal of inappropriate media and distraction. In this current era that we are living in, almost every child from a well-financed family has an electronic device, be it smart phone, or a tab or a laptop.
Most children are easily distracted and are usually attracted towards games and flashy programs/software because it appeals to them.
Their attention span is usually confined to that which interests them and it is very hard for them to focus.
    </p>

    <p>
For example, a child would usually prefer watching a movie than reading a novel. It is very difficult to allow a child to both learn something educational and at the same time be entertained.
However, what the researchers are trying to create is a program that will hopefully include both.
   </p>

    </aside>
    </div>

    <div id="footer">
        <footer>
            Copyright &copy; Kindergarten Together 2015
        </footer>
    </div>

    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: This might come in handy ... http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @smoggers - which code are you talking about?

Comment: @JibranKhatib Check if my answer works for you?

Comment: i tried adding postion:fixed; but then the navigation bar the header and the content in the footer is overlapping @smoggers

Comment: @JibranKhatib You still didn't see my answer? That's a wow! `:D` You have something in front of your eyes, but don't know what's stopping! `:P`

Comment: @PraveenKumar you have changed the whole file for me , but i want to check in the file which i submitted here.

Comment: @JibranKhatib Just replace the `aside, section, header, footer` with `#aside, #section, #header, #footer`. That's simple common sense, but is this the solution, you are expecting?

Comment: @PraveenKumar am new to this so i really need help on this

Comment: @JibranKhatib I just answered how to migrate from my answer to your solution. Didn't you understand my previous comment?

Comment: @PraveenKumar allright thank you :) will go through it throughly

Comment: @JibranKhatib Okay, I understand your situation. Check out: http://jsbin.com/rihowuvepa/edit?html,css,output. That's your code!!!

Comment: There are a lot of mistakes in your code. I will put everything in my answer. Could be a learning lesson.

Comment: @JibranKhatib Refresh and check out my answer. If you think it is a genuine help from my side!

Comment: @PraveenKumar one last question . How do I change the alignment of the text written in the <aside> ?

Comment: Like what you wanna do? Center or ... Vertically align?

Comment: @PraveenKumar make it center aligned

Comment: `text-align: center;`

Comment: okay will try and let you know @PraveenKumar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Errors in your CSS**

1. `position:relevant;` doesn't exist. It is `position: relative;`.
2. `display: auto; position: auto;` doesn't exist. It should be `display: initial;` or don't use it. The `position` is either `static | fixed | absolute`.
3. `text-align:bottom;` doesn't exist. It is either `left | center | right | justify`.

Hope the above instructions help.

---

Using your own code, I made a fiddle. Have a look at:

**Fiddle: http://jsbin.com/rihowuvepa/edit?html,css,output**

---

You might be expecting something like this?

1. Use `position: fixed;` for the items.
2. Use `padding` for the `body`.

```css
* {margin: 0; padding: 0; list-style: none; font-family: Segoe UI;}
a {text-decoration: none;}
header, footer, aside {background-color: #ccf; position: fixed; padding: 5px; text-align: center;}
body {padding: 35px 5px 35px 150px;}
header {left: 0; top: 0; width: 100%;}
aside {left: 0; width: 125px;}
footer {bottom: 0; left: 0; width: 100%;}
p {margin: 0 0 10px;}
```

```html
<header>Header</header>
<aside>
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Item 1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Item 2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Item 3</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Item 4</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Item 5</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</aside>
<section>
  <p>This is Section!</p>
  <p>Nowadays, children are being subjected to a great deal of inappropriate media and distraction. In this current era that we are living in, almost every child from a well-financed family has an electronic device, be it smart phone, or a tab or a laptop. Most children are easily distracted and are usually attracted towards games and flashy programs/software because it appeals to them. Their attention span is usually confined to that which interests them and it is very hard for them to focus.</p>
  <p>For example, a child would usually prefer watching a movie than reading a novel. It is very difficult to allow a child to both learn something educational and at the same time be entertained. However, what the researchers are trying to create is a program that will hopefully include both.</p>
  <p>Nowadays, children are being subjected to a great deal of inappropriate media and distraction. In this current era that we are living in, almost every child from a well-financed family has an electronic device, be it smart phone, or a tab or a laptop. Most children are easily distracted and are usually attracted towards games and flashy programs/software because it appeals to them. Their attention span is usually confined to that which interests them and it is very hard for them to focus.</p>
  <p>For example, a child would usually prefer watching a movie than reading a novel. It is very difficult to allow a child to both learn something educational and at the same time be entertained. However, what the researchers are trying to create is a program that will hopefully include both.</p>
  <p>Nowadays, children are being subjected to a great deal of inappropriate media and distraction. In this current era that we are living in, almost every child from a well-financed family has an electronic device, be it smart phone, or a tab or a laptop. Most children are easily distracted and are usually attracted towards games and flashy programs/software because it appeals to them. Their attention span is usually confined to that which interests them and it is very hard for them to focus.</p>
  <p>For example, a child would usually prefer watching a movie than reading a novel. It is very difficult to allow a child to both learn something educational and at the same time be entertained. However, what the researchers are trying to create is a program that will hopefully include both.</p>
</section>
<footer>This is Footer</footer>
```